# Ubuntu doesn't boot after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 14.04

I have been using Ubuntu since December, 2013. As of now I am doing good with this OS and getting acquainted with and slowly learning in-depth file structure, etc. However yesterday there was an automatic upgrade of my OS to Ubuntu 14.04. I accepted and agreed to the upgrade. Now after the upgrade has completed, my OS is not booting at all.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You tagged your question with the *dual-boot* tag. What is the other OS?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a grub problem, use boot-repair.  It works almost every time, and is a one click fix: http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Update breaks grub, resulting in "error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found"  
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289977  several fixes suggested as work arounds in bug report

Comment: @oldfred then boot-repair will most likely fix it.  It reinstalls grub

Comment: I think the standard fix of reinstalling grub to MBR or efi partition is not enough. But Boot-Repair also has a chroot and total purge & reinstall as one of its advanced options that should work.